# Why did I need to tripple annotate the column name of a MappedSuperClass

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, annotations

I had a base entity class (ignore that `id` could be in here for this example):

```java
@MappedSuperClass
public class BaseTimeEntity implements Serializable {
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_created")
    protected Timestamp timeCreated;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_updated")
    protected Timestamp timeUpdated;

    public Timestamp getTimeCreated() { return timeCreated; }

    public void setTimeCreated(Timestamp timeCreated) { this.timeCreated = timeCreated; }

    public Timestamp getTimeUpdated() { return timeUpdated; }

    public void setTimeUpdated(Timestamp timeUpdated) { this.timeUpdated = timeUpdated; }
}
```

And I had an existing entity happily using it:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner extends BaseTimeEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;
    public Owner(Integer ownerId) { this.id = ownerId; }

    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

    public Integer getId() { return this.id; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
}
```

When I added another entity I found the new entity, column, was trying to use the column name `timeCreated` instead of `time_created`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment extends BaseTimeEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String message;

    public Integer getId() { return this.id; }

    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

    @Column(name = "message")
    public String getMessage() { return message; }

    public void setMessage(String message) { message = message; }
}
```

No idea why the same base class used a different column name from the other time it is used.

So I updated the base class to:

```java
@MappedSuperClass
public class BaseTimeEntity implements Serializable {
    protected Timestamp timeCreated;

    protected Timestamp timeUpdated;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_created")
    public Timestamp getTimeCreated() { return timeCreated; }

    public void setTimeCreated(Timestamp timeCreated) { this.timeCreated = timeCreated; }

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_updated")
    public Timestamp getTimeUpdated() { return timeUpdated; }

    public void setTimeUpdated(Timestamp timeUpdated) { this.timeUpdated = timeUpdated; }
}
```

And hooray
the new entity, column, was using `time_created`.
But NO the old entity, owner, started using `timeCreated` instead of `time_created`.

So I put the annotation in triplicate everywhere:

```java
@MappedSuperClass
public class BaseTimeEntity implements Serializable {
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_created")
    protected Timestamp timeCreated;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_updated")
    protected Timestamp timeUpdated;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_created")
    public Timestamp getTimeCreated() { return timeCreated; }

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_created")
    public void setTimeCreated(Timestamp timeCreated) { this.timeCreated = timeCreated; }

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_updated")
    public Timestamp getTimeUpdated() { return timeUpdated; }

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "time_updated")
    public void setTimeUpdated(Timestamp timeUpdated) { this.timeUpdated = timeUpdated; }
}
```

Now this works, but it seems pretty poor in style. Why did the two entities both change behavior about what they use to name the column?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use? It looks suspicious that you put `@Column(name = "message")` on the method, however the `@Id` is on the field. Usually you should not mix up [access strategies](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#access).

Comment: @SternK I appear to be using Hibernate 5.2.11

Answer (score 0):

It would appear @SternK was right in that the [access strategies](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#access) are not to be mixed. Simply ensuring all column annotations are on fields only made the serializing and deserialing to DB work.

It would have been particularly more helpful if any mixed case would give compiler errors.